# Angular 2 - What is the current (correct) bootstrap process?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I want to implement Angular 2's [security functionality](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html), specifically CSRF, which uses the `XSRFStrategy` provider. The current bootstrap process I use is not recent enough to implement this provider.

This brings up the challenge of finding the best (correct?) way to load and initialize Angular 2. I have tried several approaches and the only one that works is now deprecated.

I have gotten this approach to work:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/router.dev.js"></script>
<script>
System.config({
    transpiler: "typescript",
    packages: {
        app: { main: 'app', defaultExtension: "ts" }
    }
});
System.import("app").then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I cannot get this to work (from Angular 2's [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) demo):

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script>
(function(global) {
    var map = {
        app:                          'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'https://npmcdn.com/@angular',
        '@angular/common':            'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        rxjs:                         'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10'
    };

    var packages = {
        app:                          { main: 'app', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        rxjs:                         { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade'
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
</script>
```

Nor the recommended setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868080/invalid-provider-error-while-consuming-webapi-using-http-provider) (Plunkr) from stackoverflow, dated June 16, 2016. This one specifically addresses an invalid provider error from `http`.

What is the best way to bootstrap Angular 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get this to work"?

Comment: Multiple reasons, but let's address them independently. Using Angular 2's demo https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform/common returns a 404, even though it works correctly in Plunkr.

Comment: I probably can't help you with this issues but I remember seeing this 404 error mentioned several times in other questions.

Comment: Stripping out that /platform/common request, this is the next error I get:

Error: BaseException@https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4//bundles/core.umd.js:4412:27

Comment: I have created a Plunkr based on the Angular 2 site demo that shows the errors I get: http://plnkr.co/edit/mYaPKmk0dEbW5pdPgcSw?p=preview

Comment: `main.ts` is missing `import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";` For a complete Plunker template see https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is the bootstrap process used by the angular team. 
They created this plunker to help contributors report issues.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for best practice but using online CDN? this can't be best practice. you should follow the 5 minutes quick start as is, or you can download angular 2 seed from github, there are plenty:
https://github.com/angular/quickstart

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The current **recommended** way to bootstrap/start an Angular 2 project is to use the **Angular CLI**, have a look at [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects) great post! Hope it helps ;)